# Nuxt Generate Files Show Loading Screen instead of content

Tags: nuxt.js

I'd like to get SEO-friendly content with Nuxt-generate, but there seems to be a conflict with getting past the loading screen, which I have also activated for a better UX when the initial spa app loads.

How can the generate action get past the loading screen ?

The generated files just show the loading spinner and no content

My nuxt config is:

```
ssr:false,

  generate: {
    subFolders: false,

    routes() {...}
 },
loadingIndicator: { name: 'circle', color: 'white', background: '#6cdae8' },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution: just remove: ssr:false and it works